# Get Json with php/guzzle from uri

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, laravel-artisan

i'm doing an artisan command for get the json in this webpage:
https://www.arera.it/it/atti-18.json

I'm using php/guzzle library:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.arera.it/it/atti-18.json');
echo $res->getBody();
```

But i receive this in output console:

```
<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: 5887289226846801693</body></html>
```

and not the json. Someone can help me? I'm using laravel 5.4 and the latest version of guzzle.

Comment: Is this your api or 3rd party? If 3rd party, I would recommend to contact the owner.

Comment: is 3rd party, maybe send an email to contact the owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i have solved my problem. In my client request i've added the headers array like in guzzle documentation http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers. So my client request is:

```
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.arera.it/it/atti-18.json',[
        'headers' => [
            'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36',
            'accept' => 'image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8'
            ],
        'debug' => 'true',
    ]);
```

Maybe it can help other peoples. Thank you for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

Such a message can be generated by a filter protecting the server against misuse.
Such bans usually expire in a day, so you can try again later.

Comment: Is there a method to avoid this filter? Maybe add the header in my request? Because i'm trying to get the json from 3 days and the ban is not expired.

Comment: Probably this filter blocks your ip, so you could try to use proxy or as Jerodev said contact the owner to fix this false positive.